# How to set cron job URL for CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I am using CodeIgniter for my website. I have to use cron job to run one of controller function. I am using route in website. And also I am not using `index.php` in URL.

e.g. `http://example.com/welcome/show`, here welcome is my controller and show is function name of that controller.

I have used like this,

`0 * * * * php /home/username/public_html/welcome/show`

It is giving 'No such directory'

How can I set cron jon in cPanel for above URL.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have used below cron

```
php /full-path-to-cron-file/cron.php /test/index
```

source: http://www.asim.pk/2009/05/14/creating-and-installing-crontabs-using-codeigniter/

This works for me.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 49):

Use:

```
php index.php welcome show
```

as command in your crontab. E.g.:

```
0 * * * * php /home/username/index.php welcome show
```

Source (ver. 2.2.0)
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/cli.html

Source (ver. 3.*)
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html

Source (ver. 4.*)
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/cli/cli.html

Comment: thanks, I have used this one, but it loads default controller.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of CI?

Comment: @Sachin try /usr/local/bin/php /home/user/index.php welcome show
Trick is in loading different php installation than regular /usr/bin/php

Comment: there is no `/usr/local/bin/php` in my machine

Comment: excelente, in my case was php /home/myusername/domains/example.com/public_html/index.php tasks inserttest

Answer (score 13):

You can try with this one:

```
wget api.example.com/index.php/controller/function
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, means the url like using my example is `0 * * * * wget http://my-domain.com/welcome/show`, is this right?

Comment: I think so,you can try with this

Comment: Thanks Suvash..
This url work for me.

wget yourSite.com/index.php/controller/method

Comment: i set 2 cron for every minute and these creats many tmp files .

Comment: **Be careful** if you are using it, because basically `wget` is downloading a website as a file, so your server will have so many files. For example, I run 2 times of `wget localhost/my_controller/auth`, then I check with `[root@myserver bin]# ls -l | grep auth` command, I have 2 files: 
`-rw-r--r--   1 root root          57 Feb 27 07:53 auth` and 
`-rw-r--r--   1 root root          57 Feb 27 07:53 auth.1`

Comment: This have a full negative impact on the server performance, it's much better use an a relative url at the cron jobs.

Answer (score 11):

You can also try:

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent --compressed http://example.com/welcome/show
```

Or localhost

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent --compressed http://localhost/welcome/show
```

I hope that is helpful.

Comment: could you explain this little bit

Answer (score 4):

/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/index.php controllername methodname

This worked for me.

Comment: thanks for this solution! just one quick question with this solution if i have a login in my app it would request why and how can i avoid it? @Reshma D

Answer (score 2):

Here is the cron I use

[image]

/usr/bin/php /home/pia/www/jobs/index.php cron newsletter

Explanation:

a) $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = /home/pia/www

b) codeigniter website root = /home/pia/www/jobs

c) 'cron' = controller name

d) 'newsletter' = method name

Comment: Hi, what tool is this?

Answer (score 1):

I have done it as

```
 00 09-18 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/app/index.php crontest
```

crontest is the name of the controller which also uses a model to pull data from the database and send mail periodically (between 9 AM to 6 PM on Monday to Friday every week)

I just viewed [this page](http://glennstovall.com/developer-tutorials/writing-cron-job-in-codeigniter/) which explains very detail with example. Hope this will be useful to others as well.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I am using codeigniter 3.0.3 and my server is hostgator. For me, the below format is working fine

```
*/15 * * * * /opt/php55/bin/php /home/username/public_html/myapp/index.php reminders index
```

above command runs every 15 minutes, reminders in command is controller name and index is method name.

Comment: @sachin you can try `0 * * * * php /home/username/public_html/yourapp/index.php welcome show`

Answer (score 1):

```
watch -n60 curl [your application path]/check_banalce/user_balance
```

in my case im using codeigniter and  the above command executes the user_balance function which is found in check_balance controller every 60 sec.

Answer (score 1):

On a Linux EC2 intance, this worked:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cifolder/index.php [module] [function]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Hostgator(or any other Linux server) then try this one.

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/php /YOUR_HOME_DIRECTORY/YOUR_USERNAME/public_html/marketing/index.php welcome emailcampaign 1
```

for example for me its

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/php /home3/adnan/public_html/index.php welcome emailcampaign 101
```

where

```
welcome is the controller name
emailcampaign is the function name of welcome controller
101 = First argument of url.
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up cron jobs through cPanel using this procedure:

1. Log on to your cPanel Interface.
2. Go to ''Advanced' section.
3. Click on "Cron Jobs".
4. Select the specific time from the lists provided.
5. You should enter the command to run in the "Command" field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cPanel then Use the following command:

```
/usr/bin/curl -k http://example.com/welcome/show
```

This works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am using hostgator's cPanel.
I have created a user controller and `run_cron_data` function inside the user controller.

 Command: `wget www.example.com/index.php/user/run_cron_data`

See the below screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
* * * * * php index.php controllername functionname
```

1st * - minute,
2nd * - hour,
3rd * - day of month,
4th * - month,
5th * - day of week.

For more info visit : https://crontab.guru/