# What link we need to add in cron jobs of Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to add link of codeigniter in cron jobs, but it is not working..i don't know why..:(

i am using this one:

```
php -q /home2/abisysco/asuccessclub/main/getFreeC
```

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269566/how-to-set-cron-job-url-for-codeigniter

May be link will help you

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter use a complex **URL rewriting** method, so run the php file **directly** is not a good idea. Try this:

Create a controller to do your cron job:

```
<?php
class MyCronJob extends CI_Controller {

    public function dojob()
    {
        // Put your business here
    }
}
?>
```

And then set your cron job like this:

```
wget –quiet http://domain.com/MyCronJob/dojob
```

Comment: Actually i am using codeigniter framework...in there link type is http://domain.com/class/function

Comment: and i am using php -q /home2/abisysco/asuccessclub/main/getFreeC   main is class name and getFreeC is function name

Comment: CodeIgniter use a complex URL rewriting method that cause your php file running wrong. Please use the `wget` one.