# Codeigniter PHP MYSQL - select where date = pay_day every month

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Please I really need help for this. It's is very important for my project
Please help. I am so stuck on this.

I have a table "employees"
in MySQL database  inside which I have 'payday' for employees salary day as date in field in 'employees' table.

Let's say:

payday is 
Nov 28 2015 for some employees 
Nov 25 2015 for some others

What I can't rap my head around is how to :

```
 $this->db
 ->select('*')
 ->from(employees)
 ->where (Curdate() = 'payday');
 ->get()
 count_all_result();
 Return true;
```

While this works for the first month , how then can I repeat this every 28th, 25th of every month loop through the years......

I am using framework, Codeigniter

Comment: Alert who, how? What is your data structure? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Who = user, how = notifications count in dashboard, data structure = Code igniter model API, what I have tried date_diff(curdate(),  pay_day) I don't know how to count it "every 30 days"

Answer (score 0):

I think the method that you are looking for is crone job (scheduled task), you can find sufficient information at below links:

[How to set cron job url for codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269566/how-to-set-cron-job-url-for-codeigniter)

[How to create cron job using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php)