# How to set the cron job for CodeIgniter URL using prefix?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I have an action in my project of CodeIgniter to that I want to hit with via cron.

My cron URL is `http://****.***/cron/user/sendmail`/

For this I tried:

```
* * * * * php /home/user/public_html/index.php cron user sendmail
```

Here

- cron : is the prefix
- user : controller
- sendmail : action

I have to run this with cron prefix because on the basis of this I am updating some configuration.

Comment: i have already explain it above 
cron : is the prefix
user : controller
sendmail : action

Comment: yes i want to run this /home/user/public_html/index.php but with above parameters

Comment: check this may be it would help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19514706/2815635