# i want to run cron job using codeigniter script

Tags: codeigniter

**Script code**

```
class Deposit extends MY_Controller
{
   public function coinPaymentCron()
    {
         $this->load->model('user_model','apimodel');

        $apikeys = $this->apimodel->getApiKey();

        foreach ($apikeys as $keysapi) {
            # code...
            $publickey = $keysapi->public_key;

            $privatekey = $keysapi->private_key;
        }

        $cps = new CoinPaymentsAPI();

        $cps->Setup($privatekey, $publickey);

        $getTxIds = $this->apimodel->gettxids();

        foreach ($getTxIds as $txid) {
            # code...

            $tx_id = $txid->txn_id;

            echo $tx_id;

            $txinfo = $cps->gettxinfo($tx_id);

            if ($txinfo['error'] == 'ok') {
                # code...
                $statusText = $txinfo['result']['status_text'];

                $amountReceived = $txinfo['result']['receivedf'];

                $statusPayment = $txinfo['result']['status'];

                $this->apimodel->updateStatus($tx_id, $statusText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code command i am using for running cron job is

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/name/public_html/index.php deposit coinPaymentCron
```

I have also tried many methods like using wget and curl but unfortunately none work for me. 
Also checked the script using url and the script is running fine and updating the database but the cron job is not running.
Some other cron jobs are running using this method

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/name/public_html/index.php
```

Can anyone please help regarding this issue or let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set cron job url for codeigniter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269566/how-to-set-cron-job-url-for-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

As I know there are a lot of ways to call function of CodeIgniter e.g.

This solution working for me

```
php /full-path-to-cron-file/cron.php /deposit/coinPaymentCron
```

also, you can try with this:

```
wget example.com/index.php/deposit/coinPaymentCron
```

Or

```
*/15 * * * * /opt/php55/bin/php /home/username/public_html/myapp/index.php deposit coinPaymentCron
```

But you read this tutorial: http://www.asim.pk/2009/05/14/creating-and-installing-crontabs-using-codeigniter/ and follow instruction. It will be helpful for you.