# Cron job in codeigniter on cpanel not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, cpanel

I have to use a cron job in cpanel and I am using CodeIgniter. My controller path is http://www.example.com/myfolder/application/controllers/cron/cron_controller.php How am I call my controller in cron.

Comment: In  codeigniter we can not produce this url. And share some code what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thanks Bhavin,My code is working fine in url but cron is not working. I checked my code and that is correct.

Comment: Try like                                                                                                                 curl "http://www.example.com/myfolder/application/controllers/cron/cron_controller?option=com_jnews&act=cron"

Comment: Here is another

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269566/how-to-set-cron-job-url-for-codeigniter/22995837#22995837

Answer (score 0):

In the crontab simply define

```
0 * * * * php /controllers/cron/cron_controller.php
```

it will work, Here * are variables (time)

```
Example of job definition:
.---------------- minute (0 - 59)
|  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
|  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
|  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
|  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
|  |  |  |  |
*  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to run cron, you're running from the command line, but you'll still need to go through the index. So your cron command would be:

```
* * * * * php index.php cron cron_controller
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/cli.html

Answer (score 0):

this is working . just type this in cron tab

```
wget www.yourdomain.com/index.php/yourcontroller/yourfunction
```